# Remove the first item on click in Ractive.js

Tags: ractivejs

I have a list of 4 items and I need to remove the first item every time the button is clicked. I implemented a simple solution based on splice method but it seems to work only on the first click. Any further click doesn't change a thing.

Here is the html:

```
<script type="text/ractive" id="template1">
    {{#each Posts}}
    <div style="background-color: red">{{Text}}</div>
    {{/each}}
    <button on-click="removeFirst">Remove first</button>
</script>

<main></main>
```

, javascript:

```
var ractive1 = new Ractive({
    template: '#template1',
    el: 'main',
    data: {
        Posts: [ {Text: "Post 1"}, {Text: "Post 2"}, {Text: "Post 3"}, {Text: "Post 4"} ],    
    }
});

ractive1.on({
        removeFirst: function() {
            ractive1.splice('Posts', 0, 1, []);
        }
});
```

and [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mq197dox/5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `splice` on an array, the first argument is the index from which to start removing elements, the second argument is the number of elements to remove, and *all the rest* are items to insert into the array at the same location. So what you're actually doing when you call `array.splice(0, 1, [])` is replacing the first item with an empty array, instead of just removing it.

Ractive's array mutation methods follow the same form, except that the first argument is the 'keypath' of the array. So if you do this...

```js
ractive1.splice('Posts', 0, 1);
```

...[it works correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/2L43c3t3/).

Comment: And in javascript removing the first element is a common enough operation that it has it's own method: `shift()`. In ractive you can use that on the array or use the API method like `ractive1.shift('Posts');`